# Is it possible to redefine the "projector" monitor in Windows' presentaton mode?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

I have a PC with Windows 7 Professional that has DisplayPort and HDMI outputs.  The monitor I normally use is connected using DisplayPort.  Occasionally I connect the PC to a TV via HDMI.

Alas, it seems that Windows treats the TV as monitor #1 and my normal monitor as monitor #2.  Even though I've set monitor #2 as my "main display", when I press Win+P to enter presentation mode, the "Computer only" choice switches to the TV, and the "Projector only" choice switches to my normal monitor, which is opposite of how I'd like them to be defined.

Is there any way to change this?

Comment: @sawdust Is that something new in Windows 10?  The Screen Resolution panel is where I filled the "Make this my main display" checkbox for monitor #2, but I don't see anywhere that allows me to assign display IDs.

Comment: @sawdust Er, I am using Windows 7.  I am asking you if *you're* using Windows 10, because I don't see anywhere in Windows 7 to reassign display IDs like you described.